# Escape Room Bomb Defusal Wire Cut

Tags: wiring

I am fairly new to electronics and all of that good stuff, but I have been doing some research on triggering a series of events that would simulate a movie bomb defusal. I've got an idea for four stages. I have some diagrams I've made in circuit lab, and I have a base idea for what I want, I just would like some tips and insight from a more experienced person and learn what values I need for resistors and such.

Diagram 1: Essentially what I'm trying to do in this diagram is; when the sensor wire is cut, it will allow current to pass through to an led and continue to let 12v of power from the 8 D cell batteries through the wires. If the wire isn't cut, it will not allow power through to the led. I've looked at some diagrams and done what I could to try and replicate that.

When the wire is cut, I want to power an led. I also want a key switch, that when turned, will turn on yet another led, and power a relay with 12v of power. This will, in turn, power an arduino powered keypad. Complicated, right?

[image]

Diagram 2: This diagram shows one of the three wires that is not correct. If this wire is cut, I want it to let power through to power a red Led, a 12v piezo siren,([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00HR6P9QU/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A1THAZDOWP300U&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HR6P9QU)), and, if possible, a 9v activated smoke grenade THAT CAN BE REMOVED and the circuit will still function. (http://sportsmoke.com/smoke-grenades/electric-fire/tactical-smoke-grenade-electric-fire). I know. I'm needy. I want to have two incorrect wires, and I'm wondering if I could power all three wires off of the same power source, because 8 D batteries is already a lot to fit into a case.

[image]

Diagram 3: What I want happening here is a key switch, when turned, will trigger the smoke, led, and siren. This one can be powered by separate power source, like AA batteries in series. Also, I'd appreciate if we could power the same smoke grenade by all sources.

[image]

Ok! That's all the stages

Comment: pretty cool idea ... you could probably do everything with an Arduino.

Comment: yeah, just have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I doubt this whole thing will work, so i just need some help.

Comment: As long as there is a red wire and a blue wire it will be fine :)

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. I hope this works eventually!

Comment: Also, What resistors would I use for the Leds?

Comment: Sorry, couldn’t resist :)

Comment: @SpencerLewis, `just have no idea what I'm doing wrong` ... do you have it built?

Comment: No, but knowing me, something is wrong.

Comment: With the values of R2 and R3 you've specified, about 20mA will flow, which is about right to brightly light a normal indicator LED.  If you don't want to dazzle people, you could double the resistors.  But if you want it visible in bright light, 470 ohms is about right.

Comment: do you want the wrong wire when cut to activate the alarm, and the correct wire when cut to defuse the alarm and make a LED go out?

Comment: This is a really neat project :) though I have a real funny feeling that the purpose of this is to represent dramatic irony to non-electrical engineers or electrical hobbyist LOL. You're going to confuse a lot of people and they will probably never win the game unless they randomly select a wire to cut.

Comment: Whatever you do don't cut the red wire! I remember an old movie I think it was Juggernaught try that for ideas. There were some really diabolical ideas in that

Comment: @RoyC And there are plenty of variations possible. Warning: TVTropes link [here](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WireDilemma).

Answer (score 2):

Connect all the wires to spare arduino inputs, and just have it wait until the correct wire is cut before activating the keypad.

The wrong wires can all be connected in series, and so only require a single input.

If cutting order is not important the right wires can be connected in parallel

Have the ardiuino command the LEDs noises and smoke as apropriate.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing that?